# Swift - array to data and back to string

Tags: ios, swift

I want to array string to base64 and then back to the string

I try the following

```
let array = [[1,2,"preved"], [3,4,"hola"], [5,6,"poka"]]

let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array)

let base64String = encodedData.base64EncodedString()

let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
let decodedData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
print(decodedData)
```

problem is that `decoded data` prints back nil

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are missing the reverse of `NSKeyedArchiver` => `NSKeyedUnarchiverArchiver`.

Comment: It is returning nil because you are base64 encoding the data from NSString but trying to construct it back using normal NSString initialiser. To get back the string use data!.base64EncodedString()

Comment: Replace create decodedData from NSString to 

if let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64String) {
let decodedData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data)
    print(decodedData)
}

Answer (score 5):

When using [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedarchiver)coder , [NSKeyedUnarchiver](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nskeyedunarchiver) decoder should be also used:

> NSKeyedArchiver, a concrete subclass of NSCoder, provides a way to
>   encode objects (and scalar values) into an architecture-independent
>   format that can be stored in a file. When you archive a set of
>   objects, the class information and instance variables for each object
>   are written to the archive. **The companion class *NSKeyedUnarchiver***
>   **decodes the data in an archive and creates a set of objects equivalent to the original set.**

-In the simplest way- as follows:

```
let array = [[1,2,"preved"], [3,4,"hola"], [5,6,"poka"]]

let encodedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array)

if let decodedArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: encodedData) as? [Any] {
    // ...
}
```

Note that since `array` data type is `[Array<Any>]`, you should cast it as `[Any]`